# Ошибка no such table

Tags: android

Почему-то не находит таблицу bludas в БД, хотя я создала таблицу такую в БД.. Подскажите пожалуйста почему

Вот мой класс DBHelper.java

```
public class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    private static String DB_PATH;

    public static final String DB_NAME = "bluda.db";
    public static final int DB_VERSION = 1;

    public SQLiteDatabase database;
    private Context myContext;

    public DBHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DB_NAME, null, DB_VERSION);
        this.myContext = context;
        try {
            DB_PATH = myContext.getDatabasePath(DB_NAME).toString();
            createDataBase();
            openDataBase();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public Cursor getBluda() {
        return database.query(
                Contract.Bluda.TAB_BLUDA,
                null,
                null,
                null,
                null,
                null,
                null);
    }

    public void createDataBase() throws IOException {

        boolean dbExist = checkDataBase();

        if (!dbExist) {
            this.getReadableDatabase();
            try {
                copyDataBase();
            }
            catch (IOException e) {
                throw new Error("Error copying database");
            }
        }
    }

    private boolean checkDataBase(){
        SQLiteDatabase checkDB = null;
        try {

            checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(DB_PATH, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);
        }
        catch (SQLiteException e) {
        }
        if (checkDB != null) {
            checkDB.close();
        }
        return checkDB != null;
    }

    private void copyDataBase() throws IOException {
        InputStream myInput = myContext.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);

        String outFileName = DB_PATH;

        OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);

        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int length;
        while ((length = myInput.read(buffer))>0){
            myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
        }

        myOutput.flush();
        myOutput.close();
        myInput.close();
    }

    public void openDataBase() throws SQLException {
        database = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(DB_PATH, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
    }

    @Override
    public synchronized void close() {
        if(database != null)
            database.close();
        super.close();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

    }
}
```

Класс Contract.java

```
public final class Contract {
    private Contract() {}

    public static abstract class Bluda implements BaseColumns {
        public static final String TAB_BLUDA = "bludas";

        public final static String _ID = BaseColumns._ID;
        public static final String COL_BLUDO = "bludo";
        public static final String COL_RECEPT = "recept";
        public static final String COL_LIKE = "like";
    }
}
```

Выдает вот такую ошибку

> FATAL EXCEPTION: ModernAsyncTask #1 Process: ru.test.appbluda, PID:
>   21019 java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occurred while executing
>   doInBackground() at
>   android.support.v4.content.ModernAsyncTask$3.done(ModernAsyncTask.java:161)
>   at
>   java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:354)
>   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:223)
>   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242) at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
>   at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
>   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:762) Caused by:
>   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: bludas (code
>   1): , while compiling: SELECT * FROM bludas
>
> ########################################################### Error Code : 1 (SQLITE_ERROR) Caused By : SQL(query) error or missing
>
> database. (no such table: bludas (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT *
>   FROM bludas)
>
> ########################################################### at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native
>
> Method) at
>   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:1008)
>   at
>   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:573)
>   at
>   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
>   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.(SQLiteProgram.java:59)
>   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.(SQLiteQuery.java:37) at
>   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:44)
>   at
>   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1711)
>   at
>   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.queryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1558)
>   at
>   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.query(SQLiteDatabase.java:1429)
>   at
>   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.query(SQLiteDatabase.java:1597)
>   at ru.test.appbluda.db.DBHelper.getBluda(DBHelper.java:38) at
>   ru.test.appbluda.MainActivity$MyCursorLoader.onLoadInBackground(MainActivity.java:84)
>   at
>   ru.test.appbluda.MainActivity$MyCursorLoader.onLoadInBackground(MainActivity.java:68)
>   at
>   android.support.v4.content.AsyncTaskLoader$LoadTask.doInBackground(AsyncTaskLoader.java:57)
>   at
>   android.support.v4.content.AsyncTaskLoader$LoadTask.doInBackground(AsyncTaskLoader.java:45)
>   at
>   android.support.v4.content.ModernAsyncTask$2.call(ModernAsyncTask.java:138)
>   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237) ... 3 more

Comment: Может БД не может скопировать? Хотя в другом проекте работает этот класс

Comment: Вы добавили эту таблицу позже, уже после того, как запускали проект хотя бы раз?

Comment: Да, я переименовала таблицу после первого запуска

Comment: Хммм.. разобралась. Поняла о чем вы говорите

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Удалите приложение с устройства на котором тестируете.

Дело в том, что БД создается только один раз, при первом старте приложения, в дальнейшем ее модификация производится через метод `onUpgrade()` класса `SQLiteOpenHelper` с повышением версии базы данных, но это имеет смысл только если приложение уже в релизе (у многих пользователей), для тестируемого приложения проще просто деинсталировать его, тогда будет создана база заново, уже с изменениями.

Comment: Да, спасибо.. Забыла удалить приложение(