# Ошибка при добавлении столбца в SQL

Tags: java, android, android-sqlite

Помогите с решением, я добавил новый столбец в таблицу SQL. Но в логах выводится ошибка такого рода:

```
04-08 23: 46: 27.498 18193-18193 / com.shihzamanapp.com E / SQLiteLog: (1) 
 таблица tbl_order не имеет столбца с именем Menu_quantity
 04-08 23: 46: 27.498 18193-18193 / com.shihzamanapp.com E / SQLiteDatabase: 
 Ошибка при вставке Menu_quantity = 62452999 Имя_меню = Сэндвичи с Овощями 
 Total_price = 30,0 id = 139 Количество = 3
     android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: таблица tbl_order не имеет столбца 
 с именем Menu_quantity (код 1): при компиляции: INSERT INTO tbl_order 
 (Menu_quantity, Menu_name, Total_price, id, Number) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)
     ################################################## ###############
  Код ошибки: 1 (SQLITE_ERROR) Причина: ошибка SQL (запроса) или отсутствие 
  базы 
  данных.(таблица tbl_order не имеет столбца с именем Menu_quantity (код 1): 
  при 
  компиляции: INSERT INTO tbl_order (Menu_quantity, Menu_name, Total_price, 
  id, 
   Number) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?))
  ################################################## ###############
  на android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement 
  (собственный метод)
  на android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement 
 (SQLiteConnection.java:1093)  
  на android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare 
 (SQLiteConnection.java:670)
  на android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare 
 (SQLiteSession.java:588)
  на android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram. <init> 
 (SQLiteProgram.java:59) 
  на android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement. <init> 
  (SQLiteStatement.java:31) 
  в android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertWithOnConflict 
   (SQLiteDatabase.java:1607)
   в android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insert 
  (SQLiteDatabase.java:1479)
  в com.panda.shop.DBHelper.addData 
  (DBHelper.java:220)
  в com.panda.shop.ActivityMenuDetail $ 2.onClick 
  (ActivityMenuDetail.java:194)
  в com.android.internal.app.AlertController $ ButtonHandler.handleMessage 
 (AlertController.java:166) 
 на android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:102) 
 на android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:135)
 на android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:5910)
 в java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (родной метод)
 в java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:372)
 на com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit $ MethodAndArgsCaller.run 
(ZygoteInit.java:1405)
 на com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:1200)
 04-08 23: 46: 27.518 18193-18193 / com.shihzamanapp.com E / ViewRootImpl: 
 sendUserActionEvent () mView == null
```

> **Эти классы подсвечены в логах:**
>     `в com.panda.shop.DBHelper.addData(DBHelper.java:220)`
>     `в com.panda.shop.ActivityMenuDetail $ 2.onClick(ActivityMenuDetail.java:194)`

**При клике в логе на этот класс:**
  `в com.panda.shop.DBHelper.addData(DBHelper.java:220)`

**Перенаправляет на этот метод :**
`// попросите объект базы данных вставить новые данные
        try{db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, values);}
        catch(Exception e)
        {Log.e("DB ERROR", e.toString());
            e.printStackTrace();}}`
**При клике в логе на этот класс:**
  `в com.panda.shop.ActivityMenuDetail $ 2.onClick(ActivityMenuDetail.java:194)`
**Перенаправляет на этот метод :**
 `dbhelper.addData(Menu_ID, Menu_name, quantity (Menu_price*quantity),Menu_quantity);`

**Вот мой DBHelper ,в нём я добавил** `private final String CONTACT_NUMBER_COL = " Menu_quantity ";` :

```
public class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

    String DB_PATH;
    private final static String DB_NAME = "db_order";
    public final static int DB_VERSION = 10;
    public static SQLiteDatabase db; 

    private final Context context;

    private final String TABLE_NAME = " tbl_order ";
    private final String ID = "id";
    private final String MENU_NAME = " Menu_name ";
    private final String QUANTITY = " Quantity ";
    private final String TOTAL_PRICE = " Total_price ";
    private final String CONTACT_NUMBER_COL = " Menu_quantity ";
    public DBHelper(Context context) {

        super(context, DB_NAME, null, DB_VERSION);
        this.context = context;


        DB_PATH = Constant.DBPath;
        DB_PATH = Constant2.DBPath;
        DB_PATH = Constant3.DBPath;
    }


    public void createDataBase() throws IOException{

        boolean dbExist = checkDataBase();
        SQLiteDatabase db_Read = null;


        if(dbExist){
            //ничего не делать - база данных уже существует

        }else{
            db_Read = this.getReadableDatabase();
            db_Read.close();

            try {
                copyDataBase();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                throw new Error("Error copying database");
            }
        }

    }



    private boolean checkDataBase(){

        File dbFile = new File(DB_PATH + DB_NAME);

        return dbFile.exists();

    }


    private void copyDataBase() throws IOException{

        InputStream myInput = context.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);

        String outFileName = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;

        OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);

        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int length;
        while ((length = myInput.read(buffer))>0){
            myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
        }

        myOutput.flush();
        myOutput.close();
        myInput.close();

    }

    public void openDataBase() throws SQLException{
        String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
        db = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
    }

    @Override
    public void close() {
        db.close();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

    }

    /** этот код используется для получения всех данных из базы данных */
    public ArrayList<ArrayList<Object>> getAllData(){
        ArrayList<ArrayList<Object>> dataArrays = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Object>>();

        Cursor cursor = null;

            try{
                cursor = db.query(
                        TABLE_NAME,
                        new String[]{ID, MENU_NAME, QUANTITY, TOTAL_PRICE, CONTACT_NUMBER_COL },
                        null,null, null, null, null, null);
                cursor.moveToFirst();

                if (!cursor.isAfterLast()){
                    do{
                        ArrayList<Object> dataList = new ArrayList<Object>();

                        dataList.add(cursor.getLong(0));
                        dataList.add(cursor.getString(1));
                        dataList.add(cursor.getString(2));
                        dataList.add(cursor.getString(3));
                        dataList.add(cursor.getString(4));

                        dataArrays.add(dataList);
                    }

                    while (cursor.moveToNext());
                }
                cursor.close();
            }catch (SQLException e){
                Log.e("DB Error", e.toString());
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        return dataArrays;
    }

    /** этот код используется для получения всех данных из базы данных */
    public boolean isDataExist(long id){
        boolean exist = false;

        Cursor cursor = null;

            try{
                cursor = db.query(
                        TABLE_NAME,
                        new String[]{ID},
                        ID +"="+id,
                        null, null, null, null, null);
                if(cursor.getCount() > 0){
                    exist = true;
                }

                cursor.close();
            }catch (SQLException e){
                Log.e("DB Error", e.toString());
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        return exist;
    }

    /** этот код используется для получения всех данных из базы данных */
    public boolean isPreviousDataExist(){
        boolean exist = false;

        Cursor cursor = null;

            try{
                cursor = db.query(
                        TABLE_NAME,
                        new String[]{ID},
                        null,null, null, null, null, null);
                if(cursor.getCount() > 0){
                    exist = true;
                }

                cursor.close();
            }catch (SQLException e){
                Log.e("DB Error", e.toString());
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        return exist;
    }

    public void addData(long id, String menu_name,int quantity, double total_price, int menu_quantity){
        // это ключевой держатель пары значений, используемый функциями SQLite для Android
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(ID, id);
        values.put(MENU_NAME, menu_name);
        values.put(QUANTITY, quantity);
        values.put(TOTAL_PRICE, total_price);
        values.put(CONTACT_NUMBER_COL, menu_quantity);

        // попросите объект базы данных вставить новые данные
        try{db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, values);}
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            Log.e("DB ERROR", e.toString());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void deleteData(long id){
        // попросите менеджера баз данных удалить строку данного идентификатора
        try {db.delete(TABLE_NAME, ID + "=" + id, null);}
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Log.e("DB ERROR", e.toString());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void deleteAllData(){
        // попросите менеджера баз данных удалить строку данного идентификатора
        try {db.delete(TABLE_NAME, null, null);}
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Log.e("DB ERROR", e.toString());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void updateData(long id, int quantity, double total_price){
        // это ключевой держатель пары значений, используемый функциями SQLite для Android
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(QUANTITY, quantity);
        values.put(TOTAL_PRICE, total_price);

        // попросите объект базы данных обновить строку базы данных заданного rowID
        try {db.update(TABLE_NAME, values, ID + "=" + id, null);}
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Log.e("DB Error", e.toString());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

А вот так я отправляю в заказ в корзину:

```
// когда нажали кнопку добавления, добавить меню в таблицу заказов в базе данных
        if(!temp.equalsIgnoreCase("")){
            quantity = Integer.parseInt(temp);
            if(dbhelper.isDataExist(Menu_ID)){
                    dbhelper.updateData(Menu_ID, quantity, (Menu_price*quantity));
                }else{
                    dbhelper.addData(Menu_ID, Menu_name, quantity, (Menu_price*quantity),Menu_quantity);
                }
        }else{
            dialog.cancel();
        }
      }
    });
```

Помогите пожалуйста ,самому ни как не разобраться . У меня есть в директории  `assets` файл под названием `db_order`, пытался его открыть а там какая то абракадабра ,не читается этот файл ,возможно зашифрован.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/764420/177345

Answer (score 3):

Вот эта часть отменила Вашу попытку добавления нового столбца:

```
    if(dbExist){
        //ничего не делать - база данных уже существует
```

Чтобы его все же добавить, Вам нужно или удалить файл базы - `db_order` или использовать метод `onUpgrade`

```
@Override  
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {  
  if (newVersion > oldVersion) {
     db.execSQL("ALTER TABLE tbl_order ADD COLUMN Menu_quantity INTEGER DEFAULT 0");
  }
}
```

Как верно заметил @pavlofff, для срабатывания метода `onUpgrade` следует увеличить версию базы:

```
public final static int DB_VERSION = 11;
```

---

**Добавлено**

Функции `onCreate` и `onUpgrade` вызываются, когда база данных открывается с использованием методов `SQLiteOpenHelper`: `getWritableDatabase` или `getReadableDatabase`.

В объекте `DBHelper`, показанном в вопросе, база данных открывается, используя `SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase`. Соответственно, функции `onCreate` и `onUpgrade` 
 - **не вызываются**

Добавьте в Ваш класс:

```
private SQLiteOpenHelper dbHelper;
```

Далее:

```
public DBHelper(Context context) {
    dbHelper = super(context, DB_NAME, null, DB_VERSION);
```

Далее:

```
public void openDataBase() throws SQLException{
    db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
}
```

Comment: еще нужно повысить версию базы, чтобы метод onUpgrade() был вызван

Comment: спасибо за уточнение - это важно!

Comment: @СергейНуднов - спасибо большое за ответ ,но у меня теперь не ошибка с распознаванием самой таблицы. Вот такая ошибка в логах `Код ошибки: 1 (SQLITE_ERROR)
  Причина: ошибка SQL (запроса) или отсутствие базы данных.
  (такой таблицы нет: tbl_order (код 1): при компиляции: SELECT id FROM tbl_order WHERE id = 244)`

Comment: Если Вы удалили файл базы данных, то теперь нужно задействовать код, чтобы базу данных пересоздать. Как Вы это делали, когда базы ещё не было?

Comment: @SergeyNudnov Проблема в том что это не мой проект ,это обучающий проект . Я понятия не имею каким образом был создан файл `db_order` его не получается прочесть так как он возможно зашифрован или что то ещё ,у него вообще формата нет. Поэтому я не могу перестроить этот файл или заменить его.

Comment: Файл в формате sqlite - это бинарный файл, он не предназначен для чтения человеком. Что именно Вы сделали, после чего стали получать ошибку `ошибка SQL (запроса) или отсутствие базы данных.   (такой таблицы нет: tbl_order (код 1)`? Можете ли Вы переустановить проект заново - чтобы он снова заработал - а затем пробовать свои изменения?

Comment: Можно вызвать в конструкторе метод db.setForceUpgrade , это пиинудилово перезапишет базу данных

Comment: @SergeyNudnov - я удалил файл `db_order` из директории `assets`, после чего стал получать эту ошибку . Затем восстановил этот файл из резервов и ошибка изменилась ,на : `таблица tbl_order не имеет столбца с именем Menu_quantity Причина: ошибка SQL (запроса) или отсутствие базы данных. (таблица tbl_order не имеет столбца с именем Menu_quantity (код 1): при компиляции: INSERT INTO tbl_order (Menu_quantity, Menu_name, Total_price, id, Number) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?))` _и что мне делать с этим ,удалить или заменить?_ `if(dbExist){ //ничего не делать - база данных уже существует`

Comment: @SergeyNudnov  `Menu_quantity` ни как не хочет добавляться в `db_order`.

Comment: Из моего ответа: добавьте код в метод onUpgrade, увеличьте номер версии базы данных. При следующем запуске программа должна добавить столбец

Comment: @SergeyNudnov - я добавлял ваш код в  метод onUpgrade и увеличил версию ... но ни каких изменений. Столбец не добавлен, вот ошибка   `Ошибка при вставке Menu_quantity = 62452999 Menu_name = Сэндвичи с Овощями Total_price = 20,0 id = 139 Количество = 2
                                                                       android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: таблица tbl_order не имеет столбца с именем Menu_quantity (код 1): при компиляции: INSERT INTO tbl_order (Menu_quantity, Menu_name, Total_price, id, Number) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)`

Comment: Я добавил ещё информации. Не понимаю, если Вы используете SQLiteOpenHelper, то зачем использовать другой класс при открытии базы. Вот [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14108220/9921853) есть готовый DbHelper - может Вам стоит адаптировать его?

Comment: @SergeyNudnov - Спасибо вам большое за помощь, но всё же моя проблема не решилась . По поводу готовой DbHelper , это не вариант , так как перестраивать много чего придётся ,хотелось бы всё же найти решение существующей проблемы с добавлением нового столбца. В логах ,ошибка мне указывает на два класса при клике на эти классы переводит на методы в этих классах, возможно эти методы как то связанны с этой ошибкой , я обновлю свой вопрос для лучшего  представления моей проблемы.

Comment: @SergeyNudnov я задал это же вопрос в stackoverflow EN мне в коментах написали следующее : _Не могли бы вы проверить регистр в своей таблице SQL? Похоже, что ваш запрос добавления столбца создаст столбец с именем «menu_quantity» вместо «Menu_quantity». -  Visahan_

Comment: @Ильхам sqlite не чуствителен к регистру в именах таблиц и столбцов. Сделайте тестовый проект с нормальными классами и разберитесь как изменяется sqlite таблица при увеличении версии. Пока Вы сам это не сделаете, Вам никто больше помочь не сможет